# FaultTollerance Retry for OidcClientRequestReactiveFilter plu doesn't work

Tags: segmentation-fault, jax-rs, quarkus, smallrye, oidc-client

I have a code for JAX-RS with the OidcClient provider.

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey = "acs")
@RegisterProvider(OidcClientRequestReactiveFilter.class)
public interface Test {
    @GET
    @Timeout
    @Retry
    @Path("/some-cool_path")
    String test();
        
}
```

I've added a Retry Config.

Logs are added:

```
   quarkus:
      funqy:
        export: handleRequest
      log:
        category:
          'io.smallrye.faulttolerance':
            logging:
              level: DEBUG
```

Hovewer, when it runs it doesn't log retry at all.

With @Timeout it doesn't try to retry.

I can use uni with the retry, however, I want't to know whether it is a feature or a bug?

Comment: This should work. Could you please add the fault tolerance debug log? I suspect it should provide some hints as to where the problem may be.

Comment: What version of Quarkus are you using?

Comment: @geoand, I am using 2.14.3.Final

Comment: @Ladicek, what is the best way to enable debug logs? It doen't log anything now. Mystically, the server didn't receive any retries on failure. Timeout works, Retry - not. Thank your, in advance, Irina.

Comment: I suspect that there is something in the priority order in processing, but I don't understand yet what

Comment: See https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#runtime-configuration for how to configure logging. Your example has `logging.level` at the end, which is incorrect, it should be just `level`. Additionally, you may want to enable TRACE logging for SmallRye Fault Tolerance, that has a bit more info.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Ladicek, logs fixed by removing logging world.